# Python:Traceback (most recent call last):raise ConnectionError(e, request=request) requests.exceptions.ConnectionError:

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, api, python-requests, binance

This is the script:

```
import pandas as pd
from binance.client import Client
from pandas import DataFrame as df
import ta
import time
import math
import urllib3
import os, sys
import datetime
import requests
import win32api
import numpy as np

startTime = datetime.datetime.now()
request_delay = 200000


#client = Client("","", {"verify": False, "timeout": 30000})




gt = client.get_server_time()
tt=time.gmtime(int((gt["serverTime"])/1000))
win32api.SetSystemTime(tt[0],tt[1],0,tt[2],tt[3],tt[4],tt[5],0)


urllib3.disable_warnings(urllib3.exceptions.InsecureRequestWarning)
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 156, in _new_conn
>       conn = connection.create_connection(
>     File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\connection.py", line 61, in create_connection
>       for res in socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, socket.SOCK_STREAM):
>     File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\socket.py", line 918, in getaddrinfo
>       for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
>   socket.gaierror: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 665, in urlopen
>       httplib_response = self._make_request(
>     File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 376, in _make_request
>       self._validate_conn(conn)
>     File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 994, in _validate_conn
>       conn.connect()
>     File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 300, in connect
>       conn = self._new_conn()
>     File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 168, in _new_conn
>       raise NewConnectionError(
>   urllib3.exceptions.NewConnectionError: : Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 439, in send
>       resp = conn.urlopen(
>     File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 719, in urlopen
>       retries = retries.increment(
>     File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\retry.py", line 436, in increment
>       raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
>   urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.binance.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /api/v1/ping (Caused by NewConnectionError(': Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed'))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "btc.py", line 21, in 
>       client = Client("","")
>     File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\binance\client.py", line 105, in **init**
>       self.ping()
>     File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\binance\client.py", line 393, in ping
>       return self._get('ping')
>     File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\binance\client.py", line 237, in _get
>       return self._request_api('get', path, signed, version, **kwargs)
>     File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\binance\client.py", line 202, in _request_api
>       return self._request(method, uri, signed, **kwargs)
>     File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\binance\client.py", line 196, in _request
>       self.response = getattr(self.session, method)(uri, **kwargs)
>     File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 543, in get
>       return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)
>     File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 530, in request
>       resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
>     File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 643, in send
>       r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
>     File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 516, in send
>       raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)
>   requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.binance.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /api/v1/ping (Caused by NewConnectionError(': Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed'))

Is there any solution? Thank a lot

Comment: Improved formatting of code

Answer (score 0):

getaddrinfo failed indicates that you can not resolve DNS ....

If the hostname can not be resolved there is no IP to connect to and then all the other errors occur.